# MySQL: Finding the first and last dates of a year from a given `Date` object

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have a table caled "Ongoing_Portfolio" Below is its structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `ongoing_portfolio` (
 `idOngoing_Portfolio` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Updated_Date` date NOT NULL,
 `Investment_Value` double NOT NULL,
 `Cash_Value` double NOT NULL,
 `idPortfolio` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idOngoing_Portfolio`),
 KEY `fk_Ongoing_Portfolio_Portfolio1_idx` (`idPortfolio`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Ongoing_Portfolio_Portfolio1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPortfolio`) REFERENCES `portfolio` (`idPortfolio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to get the first day and last day of `Updated_Date` year. Below is my attempt.

```
//Get the first date
SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM `Updated_Date`) 
FROM Ongoing_Portfolio WHERE `idPortfolio` = 1

//Get the last date
SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM `Updated_Date`) 
FROM Ongoing_Portfolio WHERE `idPortfolio` = 1
```

I know my attempt is not completed, but that is also incorrect. I am getting errors!

What I expected is, if the `Updated_Date` is `2014-05-06` the first query should return `2014-01-01` and the second query should return `2014-12-31`

How can I do this in MySQL please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one query for getting first and last day

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(`Updated_Date`),1)  as first_date ,MAKEDATE(YEAR(`Updated_Date`),365)  as last_date FROM Ongoing_Portfolio WHERE `idPortfolio` = 1
```

You can easily access first_date and last_date from db results